# Subscribing to Observer then outputting the response to console returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

When i subscribe to an API Endpoint provided by a service in an Angular Component, I cannot access the valus from the observable in my typescript code, I can however see them in HTML.

**role.service.ts**

```
getAllRoles() {
    return this.http.get<Role[]>(`${environment.privateApiUrl}/Role/Get`);
}
```

**app-component.component.ts**

```
  roles: Role[];

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.roleService.getAllRoles().subscribe(data => {
      this.roles = data
    })

    console.log(this.roles) <-- Returns undefined
  }
```

If I call roles in my HTML however, I can see all the values. if I call console.log inside the subscribe, I can see the values.

How do I get access to this object in Typescript after i've subscribed to it?

Thanks

Comment: You should add the console inside the subscribe callback to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subscription is a contract between Observable and Observer. As the documentation state: "Subscribing to an Observable is like calling a function that delivers callbacks to which the data is delivered. [...] The execution produces multiple values over time, either synchronously or asynchronously. There are three types of values an Observable Execution can deliver:

- "Next" notification: sends a value such as a Number, a String, an Object, etc.
- "Error" notification: sends a JavaScript Error or exception.
- "Complete" notification: does not send a value."

A subscription can look like this:

```
// get something
this.http.get<any[]>(`${AppConfig.settings.whatever}`).subscribe({
        next: (res: Array<any>) => {
          this.bucket = res;
          console.log('Response object: ', res);
        },
        error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => { console.error('An error in getSomething occured', err.type) },
        complete: () => { 
          console.log('getSomething completed!');
          this.someService.setResponseObject(this.bucket);
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
      })
```

Have a look in here:

- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable#anatomy-of-an-observable

And maybe watch this video:

- https://academind.com/learn/javascript/understanding-rxjs/obervables-observers-subscriptions/

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Subscriptions` are asynchronous code. Therefore the `console.log` gets executed before your handler copies the data. If you put the `console.log` inside the subscribe it'll work.

If you want to have access later you could do something like

```
observable.subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data
  this.dataFunction()
})
```

And have the `dataFunction()` inside the component access this.data after because it will be defined by then.

Comment: I suspected something like that. Okay, back to the drawing board. No way to make it wait?

Comment: Subscriptions aren't exactly asynchronous. Probably `getAllRoles()` is an asynchronous observable. For example, `of(1)` instead of that service method will likely execute `console.log` in the right order, even if it's not in the subscriber function. You should change the scheduler to make `of` behaves asynchronously.

Comment: There's no way that i know of to make it wait so it is synchronous. 
Angular also heavily relies on RxJS and its reactive approach to things, so you might be better off trying to implement a more reactive solution than trying to "swim against the current"

Comment: Indeed, if the original observable isn't synchronous, just go with the streamflow and refactor your component. It's the best thing to do. My comment was more in the direction of demystifying a little bit `rxjs`. The "asynchronous" thing gives people cold feet even though observables are merely regular functions used in a clever way. Just to reinforce my previous comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-44nrmi?devtoolsheight=60

Answer (score 1):

Call the `console.log` inside the subscriber function.

```js
roles: Role[];

ngOnInit(): void {

  this.roleService.getAllRoles().subscribe(data => {
    this.roles = data
    console.log(this.roles);
  });
}
```